# Android Studio - Removed dependency is not removed from external libraries

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

In Android Studio, I'm implementing some libraries in the gradle file to be used in my app, these libraries got added to the external libraries section in the project, each with it's own version.

Now when I delete the dependency of one of these libraries from my gradle file, it's not getting deleted from the external libraries section, and it's extracted classes can be imported and used normally in the app, which is a big ques mark for me.

[image]

Also when changing one of these libraries version(downgrading at my case), the updated version is not getting reflected in the external libraries section, and instead, the version in the external libraries section is the one who is used in the app, which forces me to use a version that I don't want to use.

[image]

[image]

I've tried "build project" and even "invalidate and restart" but nothing changes, what am I missing here?!!

Comment: I would be curious to see if there is a real answer to this, I have had this a few times now, usually with firebase. I have been removing the dependency, then deleting the external library files and then re-adding everything.

Comment: @Notsileous the first answer of Martin didn't help but his suggestion of looking for that library in another modules was correct, I found it in another module.
All you have to do is to exclude the library from this module and everything will be great, and to know which module it is you can simple do a trial-and-error by excluding the library from the modules and see which module will make the library disappears from the cache when excluding it from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in directory `.idea/libraries` there's a cached `xml` file, which has to be deleted.

also "invalidate caches and restart" should cause this to refresh.

Additionally, there are further caches; build directory/directories and ~/.gradle/caches in the user profile... or there might be some other module, which still has it referenced.

Comment: I tried that also but same result, after deleting and restarting the cached file pops again with the older version and so the external libraries, despite when deleting the cached xml file I found the external library got deleted also.
It's driving me crazy.

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat there are further caches; `build` directory/directories and `~/.gradle/caches` in the user profile... or there might be some other module, which still has it referenced.

Comment: Thank you, I did some investigations and you were right it was being used by another library, all I had to do is to edit the gradle file by excluding the meant library from the other library that is dependent on it and use the version I prefer in the library dependency.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely explanation, and confirmed in comments of another answer, is that the library that was declared as a first level dependency also was a transitive dependency of another library.

Similarly for the version, when changing it on the first level dependency declaration, it was still upgraded to another version through a transitive dependency and conflict resolution.

Comment: That's absolutely correct, and talking about that, any idea how to force the app to take the first level dependence libraries as the highest priority?

Comment: Gradle has a number of solutions for this, have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/managing_transitive_dependencies.html)